# Why getDeclaredMethod with Class as second param throws NoSuchMethodException?

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I want to test a private method using reflection. In this case `isEdible` method from `Food` class.

```
public class Food {

  private Boolean isEdible() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

When I'm using `getDeclaredMethod` without specifying Food class, it ran successfully.

```
@Test
  public void foodTestOne() throws Exception {
    Food food = new Food();
    Method method = food.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEdible");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    boolean isEdible = (boolean) method.invoke(food);
    assertTrue(isEdible);
  }
```

But when I add `Food` Class on a second parameter I got `NoSuchMethodException`.

```
@Test
  public void foodTestTwo() throws Exception {
    Food food = new Food();
    Method method = food.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEdible", Food.class);
    // execution stop here
  }
```

My questions are:

1. What should I put in second parameters to make it work? Changing `getDeclaredMethod("isEdible", Boolean.class)` still throws the same Exception.
2. It seems pretty basic and intuitive, why is this happening?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for `getDeclaredMethod()`?  What is the purpose of the `Class<?>` argument?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't. This is clearly explained in the javadoc * @param parameterTypes the parameter array. I should've read the docs first.

Comment: ALWAYS read the Javadoc thoroughly before asking.  You'll learn something in the process.

Comment: Noted. Lesson learned the hard way.

Comment: If it helps, we've all been there, done that.

Comment: Why are you putting in a second parameter when you don't known what it does, and when you have working code? What exactly is the thought process here?

Comment: actually in the actual coding session, it's the reverse @EJP . I'm just curious on why it doesn't work the way I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getDeclaredMethod` needs to match the argument types that the method expects. When a method takes no arguments (such as `isEdible()`) you can pass `null` (or an empty `Class[]`), for example

```
public class Food {

    private Boolean isEdible() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food food = new Food();
        try {
            Class<?>[] methodArgumentTypes = null; // {};
            Object[] methodArguments = null; // new Object[0];
            Method method = food.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEdible", 
                    methodArgumentTypes);
            System.out.println(method.invoke(food, methodArguments));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Will actually invoke `isEdible()` and output `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done like this, if method has no parameters:

```java
obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, (Class<?>[]) null).invoke(obj);
```

[Read more...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/method.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that in the line

```
Method method = food.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEdible", Food.class);
```

You specify Food as a parameter of the method; it is not. Instead, you should have

```
Method method = food.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isEdible");
```

isEdible() is declared private, so you will not be able to access it in the current context, even with getDeclaredMethod. To allow for access, you can set it to accessible before invoking the method.

```
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(food);
```